# Message from client side is received in server side but don't know how to use it globally in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am beginner so please help me. I currently build a simple chat with socket.io and express in node.js.

Problem:

I send the message from the client side.

client.js

```
user_send.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    const msg = user_msg.value;
    
    //emit message to server
    socket.emit('chatMessage',msg);
});
```

and I receive it in server side

server.js

```
   socket.on('chatMessage', msg =>{
    io.emit('message',msg);

   console.log(msg);
   
 
   });
```

but don't khow how to use msg parameter which has to show in html
I currently use **ejs.js**

I just want that the msg paramater is stored in variable which can be used inside of ejs call function.

the ejs code is:

```
app.get("/", (req,res) =>{

 
  res.render("index",{messagedata: msg});
});
```

full code of client.js

```
const socket = io();


const user_send =document.querySelector(".send-btn");
const user_msg=document.querySelector(".input-msg");


//message from server
socket.on('message',message=>{
  console.log(message);
})

//getting socketid from server
socket.on('socketid',socketid=>{
  console.log(socketid);
  
});


//ading eventlistner in message send button
user_send.addEventListener("click",()=>{

    //get mesage from text filed
    const msg = user_msg.value;

    //emit message to server
    socket.emit('chatMessage',msg);
});
```

full code of server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const mysql =require("mysql")
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const io = socketio(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000




//for ejs view Engine
app.set('view engine','ejs');


app.get("/", (req,res) =>{

 
  res.render("index",{messagedata: **I just want that the reveived msg can use here**});
});





//set a static folder
//import path among other dependencies.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));



//run when client connect
io.on('connection', socket => {

   console.log('someone is just connect..');
   // welcome current user
   socket.emit('message','welcome to chat-app');
   
   //Broadcast when the user connect.
   socket.broadcast.emit('message','user '+socket.id+' connect to the chat');
   
   //sending socketId to the coient side
   socket.broadcast.emit('socketid',socket.id);

   
   //run when user disconnect
   socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
    io.emit('message','user has disconnect the chat');
   });

   //listen chatMessage
   socket.on('chatMessage', msg =>{
    io.emit('message',msg);

   console.log(msg);
   
 
   });

  
});




//run when the server is runing
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: take a look of this https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: I want to use the msg received from client side to outside of io.connection function...there is nothing mentioned about it.   If you have any idea please help me.